# How to send a generic object in place of a Type variable (or Any) in Scala

Tags: scala, functional-programming

I'm solving problem 20 on this page - http://aperiodic.net/phil/scala/s-99/

This is the code I have written

```
import scala.annotation.tailrec
import scala.collection.immutable.Nil
import scala.collection.immutable.ListSet

object Problem20 extends App {
  def removeAt[A](order: Int, xs: List[A]): (List[A], A) = {
    def removeAtRec(xs: List[A], acc: (List[A], A), i: Int): (List[A], A) =
      (xs, i) match {
        case (Nil, _)                    => (acc._1.reverse, acc._2)
        case (x :: xs_, i) if i == order => removeAtRec(xs_, (acc._1, x), i + 1)
        case (x :: xs_, i)               => removeAtRec(xs_, (x :: acc._1, acc._2), i + 1)
      }
    removeAtRec((xs, (Nil, ### What should I put here ###), 0) 
  }

  println(removeAt(3, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'g, 'h, 'i, 'j, 'k)))
  println(removeAt(0, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'g, 'h, 'i, 'j, 'k)))
  println(removeAt(10, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'g, 'h, 'i, 'j, 'k)))
  println(removeAt(11, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'g, 'h, 'i, 'j, 'k)))
  println(removeAt(12, List('a, 'b, 'c, 'd, 'e, 'f, 'g, 'h, 'i, 'j, 'k)))
}
```

I want to send an object at the placeholder `### What should I put here ###`. In Python, Java, I can send a null. But in scala it breaks. I want to send some object which I know will be overriden for sure.

Comment: `def removeAt[A](idx: Int, xs: List[A]): (List[A], Option[A]) =  xs.patch(idx,List.empty[A],1) -> xs.lift(idx)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Idiomatically we use `Option` instead of `null`, for example

```
def removeAt[A](order: Int, xs: List[A]): (List[A], Option[A]) = {
  @tailrec def removeAtRec(xs: List[A], acc: (List[A], Option[A]), i: Int): (List[A], Option[A]) =
    (xs, i) match {
      case (Nil, _)                    => (acc._1.reverse, acc._2)
      case (x :: xs_, i) if i == order => removeAtRec(xs_, (acc._1, Some(x)), i + 1)
      case (x :: xs_, i)               => removeAtRec(xs_, (x :: acc._1, acc._2), i + 1)
    }
  removeAtRec(xs, (Nil, None), 0)
}

removeAt(42, List('a', 'b')) // res5: (List[Char], Option[Char]) = (List(a, b),None)
```